# Running bash script in parallel

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing

I have a very simple command that I would like to execute in parallel rather than sequential.

```
>for i in ../data/*; do ./run.sh $i done
```

run.sh processes the input files from the ../data directory and I would like to perform this process all at the same time using a shell script rather than a Python program or something like that. Is there a way to do this using [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)?

Comment: parallel ./run.sh ::: ../data/*

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
FILES=(../data/*)
[[ ${#FILES[@]} -gt 0 ]] && printf '%s\0' "${FILES[@]}" | parallel -0 --jobs 2 ./run.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not used GNU Parallel but you can use `&` to run your script in the background. Add a `wait` (optional) later if you want to wait for all the scripts to finish.

```
for i in ../data/*; do ./run.sh $i & done
# Below wait command is optional
wait
echo "All scripts executed"
```

Comment: Aaaaaaand, KABOOM! Forgot about the &. I would still like to see this done using Parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
find ../data -maxdepth 1 -name '[^.]*' -print0 | parallel -0 --jobs 2 ./run.sh
```

The name argument of the find command is needed because you used shell globbing `../data/*` in your example and so we need to ignore files starting with a dot.